# ArrayList in Java doesn't implement methods from Collection interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am a bit confused of that problem currently. I noticed that ArrayList is a class which implements List, which in turn extends Collection.

In `Collection<?>` we have a bunch of methods and one recognizable is `containsAll()`. I looked at the official documentation for `ArrayList` but what can be seen there is that Array list has no such a method. There is something written in the footer of the page, saying "inherited methods" and `containsAll()` is mentioned there.

What I don't understand (from the documentation) is, is the `containsAll()` defined even if it's with an empty body in the ArrayList class or not at all? If not is this some sort of violation of the rules of Java?

There are others "missing" in the same way?!

Comment: "inherited" != "missing"! Did you really think the published, official Java API that comes with the language would contain "some sort of violation of the rules of Java"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`containsAll()` method is defined by `AbstractCollection` which is extended by `AbstractList`, which is in turn extended by `ArrayList`. So `ArrayList` inherits `containsAll()` implementation.

Consider the following code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
boolean contains = list.containsAll(Arrays.asList("b", "c"));
```

Here, when `list.containsAll()` is called, actually the method declared in `AbstractCollection` is executed.

Answer (score 3):

ArrayList extends AbstractList, which extends [AbstractCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)).

And there you can find it:

> Returns true if this collection contains all of the elements in the specified collection.
>
> This implementation iterates over the specified collection, checking each element returned by the iterator in turn to see if it's contained in this collection. If all elements are so contained true is returned, otherwise false.

Basically the real answer here is: pay attention to the **top** of the javadoc for ArrayList, there you can find the inheritance tree:

```
java.lang.Object
  java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
    java.util.AbstractList<E>
      java.util.ArrayList<E>
```